# Spring boot REST API Missing URI template variable

Tags: java, rest, api, maven, spring-boot

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x) to build REST API using Spring boot. It taught alot. But What I am trying to do really got me stuck.
What I am trying to get is:

```
{
     "marks":{
          "id":"1",
          "name":"test",
          "remark":"passed",
          "course": {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Spring Boot",
              "description": "Solves many problems",
              "topic": {
                 "id": "1",
                 "name": "Java",
                 "description": "Powerful Programming Language"
    }
}
```

But I get the error when I tried to add the marks-  as :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1515600105327,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException",
    "message": "Missing URI template variable 'courseId' for method parameter of type String",
    "path": "/topics/1/courses/1/marks"
}
```

My Marks Model is:

```
public class Marks {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String remark;

    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic;

    public Marks() {

    }

    public Topic getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(Topic topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public Marks(String id, String name, String remark,String topicId, String courseId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.remark = remark;
        this.topic = new Topic(topicId, "","");
        this.course = new Course(courseId, " ", " ", " ");
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

And `MarksController.java`:

```
public class MarksController {

    @RestController
    public class MarksController {

    @Autowired
    private MarksService marksService;

    @RequestMapping("/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}/marks")
    public List<Marks> getAllMarks(@PathVariable String courseId) {
        return marksService.getAllMarks(courseId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/topics/{topicId}/courses{courseId}/marks")
    public void addMarks(@RequestBody Marks marks,@PathVariable String topicId ,@PathVariable String courseId) {
        marks.setTopic(new Topic(topicId, "", ""));
        marks.setCourse(new Course(courseId, "", "", ""));
        marksService.addMarks(marks);
    }
}
```

And `MarksService.java`:

```
public class MarksService {

    @Service
    public class MarksService {

    @Autowired
    private MarksRepository marksRepository;

    public void addMarks(Marks marks) {
        marksRepository.save(marks);
    }
}
```

And `MarksRepository.java`:

```
public interface MarksRepository extends CrudRepository<Marks, String> {

    public List<Marks> findByCourseId(String courseId);

    public List<Marks> findByTopicId(String topicId);

}
```

Can anyone help me get the result as in the mentioned JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For the `POST` method

This:

```
/topics/{topicId}/courses{courseId}/marks
```

Should be:

```
/topics/{topicId}/courses/{courseId}/marks
```

Note the additional / between `courses` and `{courseId}`

### For the `GET` method

This:

```
/topics/{topicId}/courses/{id}/marks
```

Should be:

```
/topics/{topicId}/courses/{courseId}/marks
```

Note the use of `courseId` to agree with the parameter name in `MarksController.getAllMarks`.

Comment: Thanks. Will do the change.

What I am trying to do is add the marks, but it gives the error. :/

Comment: I think the question is clear. This error message: "Missing URI template variable 'courseId' ..." for the path: "/topics/1/courses/1/marks" tells us that Spring was unable to populate the `courseId` parameter of `MarksController.getAllMarks`. The reason for this is that the annotation on that method does not declare `{courseId}` instead it declares `{id}`. The names of the placeholder parameters in the @RequestMapping annotation must match the names of the parameters to the annotated method. There's a similar error in the POST method so I mentioned that in the answer too.